# How to make python web server to respond on IP adress?

Tags: python, web-services, http, webserver, python-server-pages

I am testing some python functionalities as web server. Typed :

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

...and setup port forwarding on router to this 8080. I can access via web with http://my.ip.adr.ess:8080/, whereas my.ip.adr.ess stands for my IP adress.

When I started my xampp server it is accessible with http://my.ip.adr.ess/ and no 8080 port is required for accessing.

What should I have to do to python server responds like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that xampp is running on port 80 which is default for http://. You need to run SimpleHTTPServer on that port too. [More info about running SimpleHTTPServer on port 80](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24598/how-can-i-start-the-python-simplehttpserver-on-port-80).

Comment: And thats it !!!! I thought that 8080 stands for 80 start and 80 ending port.... Of course, it worked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the port as `80` (default port for HTTP protocol).

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

You may need superuser permission in Unix to bind port 80 (under 1024).

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```